Definition of elements in ReactJs
This is a minor question
Can one define a div element in upperCase?
I tried using it and i have no errors in my project and as im definin a set element im getting no erros.
Can this syntax be used along side the standard one?
 <DIV className="pricing">
                {pricingPlans.map(plan      =>(
                    <p key={feature}>
                        <i className="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>
                        {feature}
                    </p>
                ))}
            </DIV>


Yes, since internally DIV is the tagName of the element. HTML Parsing doesn't care about capitals, and considers div equal to DIV as a tagName. But why do that?

Couldn’t reproduce.

In HTML and JSX, tags are case-insensitive meaning that you can technically use uppercase tags like <DIV> instead of the standard lowercase <div>.
However, it's highly recommended to use the standard lowercase tags for consistency, readability, and to adhere to conventional coding practices.
Using uppercase tags might not cause errors, but it can lead to confusion for other developers who read your code and expect standard practices. Additionally, some linters and code quality tools might flag this as an issue.
That's why we have to use lowercase for built-in JSX elements.
<div className="pricing">
    {pricingPlans.map(plan => (
        <p key={plan.feature}>
            <i className="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>
            {plan.feature}
        </p>
    ))}
</div>


I agree, up to the "have to", as you just explained, you don't really have to, they're more like "guidelines".

HTML yes, JSX no.

You can use uppercase tag names, and it’s not a big deal. However, the convention is to use lowercase tag names for better readability. So don't worry, just go for it.

You can use uppercase tags like <DIV> in JSX (JSX is case-sensitive), and it will work, but it's best practice to use lowercase (e.g., <div>) for standard HTML elements.
Using uppercase tags might lead to confusion because React interprets uppercase tags as custom components. For standard HTML elements, it's best practice to stick with lowercase. So while your code will work, it's advisable to use  instead of .
If you're working alone, there’s no problem. However, if multiple developers are collaborating on the same project, it could lead to confusion and result in unreadable code.
